# Saving R script as an object that can be called from R

Tags: r

I have an R script/functions that performs the desired job, say something as simple as

meansummary<-function(x) c(avg = round(mean(x), 6), se = round(sd(x)/(NROW(x) - sum(is.na(x))),6))

quantile3summary<-function(x) c(avg = round(quantile(x, 0.75), 6), se = round(sd(x)/(NROW(x) - sum(is.na(x))),6))

quantile1summary<-function(x) c(avg = round(quantile(x, 0.25), 6), se = round(sd(x)/(NROW(x) - sum(is.na(x))),6))

I would like to be able to save it into an .RData or .RDS object so that I can load it from another R script and be able to call the function.
The objective is ***to separate the code from the actual script*** that wants to call this periodically and also keep it ***hidden since this is being provided to a client.***

So far, what I could think of, since I know we save objects of the output of regression as objects, create an empty object and put all the functionality as the object's functions and save the object into an RDS or Rdata object/file. And the script that wants to run this functionality periodically can load this object and periodically call its functions.
If any one can guide me on this approach or some other approach, would be really helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Probably, guys who are downvoting the question can comment why this is such a dumb question. It will help in the future.

Comment: Have you considered providing a private R package to the client alongside scripts? If the function is being loaded into the session the user is always going to have some way of seeing what it does - so why should the code be hidden from the client?

Answer (score 1):

Save your functions in a script and call from another script using `source("functions.R")`

Comment: I want the original functions.R opaque to the user, since I am providing this to a client. I would want this provided similar to a dll/.so in a c++ environment.

Answer (score 1):

```
fun_list = list(
    meansummary = meansummary,
    quantile3summary = quantile3summary,
    quantile1summary = quantile1summary
)

saveRDS(fun_list, "fun_list.RDS")

# new session
fun_list = readRDS("fun_list.RDS")
list2env(fun_list, globalenv())

meansummary(1:5)
```

However this method doesn't protect code from reverse engineering.

Comment: Thanks Gregory. This was what exactly I was looking for. A less than perfect solution is totally good enough for an imperfect environment. I appreciate the comments, Greg and zacdav.